# Code ends in FormatException in C# insert query to SQL Server when no values are given

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, null

I wrote this C# code to insert data into my SQL Server database:

```
DataClasses1DataContext conn = new DataClasses1DataContext();  

if (tbl.Text.Contains("GEN_EXPERIMENTS"))
{
    conn.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

    foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            GEN_EXPERIMENT addtable = new GEN_EXPERIMENT()    
            {
                EXPERIMENT_ID = Convert.ToByte(dr[0]),
                EXPERIMENT_PRICE = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[1]),
                EXPERIMENT_COST = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[2]),
                EXPERIMENT_DOC = Convert.ToString(dr[3]),
                EXPERIMENT_PATIENT = Convert.ToString(dr[4])
            };    

            conn.GEN_EXPERIMENTs.InsertOnSubmit(addtable);
        }                            
    }

    conn.SubmitChanges();
    MessageBox.Show("File uploaded successfully"); 
}
```

I'm trying to handle NULLS for `EXPERIMENT_PRICE` and `EXPERIMENT_COST`. My question is how to best handle the code for format exceptions when no values are given?

This is how the table is in the database:

[image]

The error I get when I try inserting the data to the database is this:

[image]

The data I'm trying to upload is like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you show how these two fields defined in your entity?

Comment: In any case calling Convert.Toxxxx on a DBNull.Value cannot work

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I have update the question with the image of the entity

Comment: That exception has nothing to do with null - the string you're trying to convert to a decimal is not in a format that can be converted. Please update the title and description of the problem. Also, please include the exception text, not an image of the exception, and expand the column widths so we can read the column names. In other words, make it as easy for people to help you as possible. :)

Comment: Got it. Updated. Not sure about the exception text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like this?:

```
EXPERIMENT_PRICE = (DBNull.Value.Equals(dr[1]) ? default(decimal?) : Convert.ToDecimal(dr[1])
```

It will set the `EXPERIMENT_PRICE` property to `null` if the column value is `DbNull.Value`, i.e. if you get a `null` value back from the database.

**Edit:** Are you sure that you don't have empty strings instead of `null` in the columns? Also try this:

```
EXPERIMENT_PRICE = ( DBNull.Value.Equals(dr[1]) || dr[1].ToString().Trim().Equals(string.Empty) ) ? default(decimal?) : Convert.ToDecimal(dr[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

[DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx) has a method [IsNull(int)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chk182xa(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes a columnindex, this would be the best way to check if the value is null or not.

Code fragment:

```
EXPERIMENT_ID = Convert.ToByte(dr[0]),
EXPERIMENT_PRICE = dr.IsNull(1) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dr[1].ToString()) ? null : (decimal?) Convert.ToDecimal(dr[1]),
EXPERIMENT_COST = dr.IsNull(2) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dr[2].ToString()) ? null : (decimal?) Convert.ToDecimal(dr[2]),
EXPERIMENT_DOC = dr.IsNull(3) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dr[3].ToString()) ? null : dr[3].ToString(),
EXPERIMENT_PATIENT = dr.IsNull(4) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dr[4].ToString()) ? null : dr[4].ToString()
```

#### Edit

After seeing your update you need to also check for empty strings. This will still not address any issues you might have if the string in the excel sheet is formatted incorrectly but assuming that does not happen then this would work. The proper way to check if a string is empty or contains only white space characters is with `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`. See the code change above.

Comment: I tried both ways, but still getting the same error. I have updated the question

Comment: @mm8 I tried with both nulls and empty strings. It worked with Empty strings!